# calling javascript method from UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

```
[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myfunc('%@')",string]];
```

This above code works very well and absolutely no problem but only when my javascript method is present in the page which i am loading. But if the js method is referred in any external js file it is not being triggered and this is how i am loading my page

```
       [self.webview loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example/mypage.html"]]];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ensure that your external js file was parsed? The method must be known to WebView at time of calling.

Comment: the method is globally defined in js file and the js file is referred in the html file as  <script type="text/javascript" src="webview-script.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that your javascript function will be called only *after* the page is completely loaded, you have to call it inside the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` implementation.

So, for example:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myfunc('%@')",string]];
    // Do any additional stuff
}
```